# SDL 2.0 BMP Blit screen / Update won't show picture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I ran into an issue with getting my picture to display.  I couldn't get the picture to show up in the window.

I accidentally ran the program twice (two windows) and the second window had the image in it. I can close the first and the image holds in the second window. It looks sketchy if I moved the window around.

Said all that to ask, why would my picture only show in a 2nd(3rd 4th) window and not the original.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    
    bool quit = false;

    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window * gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_Yo",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640,480,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
    if( gScreenSurface == NULL )
            {
            SDL_Quit();
           }
    SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("IMG_0004.bmp");
    if( gHelloWorld == NULL )
        {
        SDL_Quit();
       }
    SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

    quit = SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just throw something to be drawn once and expect it to stay on screen. What you've described in question is exactly how window manager operates - if some part of your window is not shown, there is no need to update it. But once it is visible again, window manager sends you a message that you need to redraw, as there is no image data held anywhere and display system have nothing to display. You didn't redraw, so some garbage (stuff that was there before) is being displayed.

As to why you didn't see image initially even though nothing was overshadowing your window - is because you've displayed your image too early. Same deal, SDL gives you an event when you need to draw.

Adequate event looop shoold be something like this:

```
while (!quit)
{
    // get all events from event queue
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    // all your display 'redraw' stuff here
    SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
}
```

If you really want SDL_WaitEvent instead, you should watch for SDL_WINDOWEVENT with SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED and SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN flags as your signal to redraw.

Comment: Thanks keltar. There are a few things I'm not grasping  1) The tutorial code is from a reliable source, if it was simply faulty code I would think others would be complaining.  2) I'm not understand the timing thing.  Are you saying to display a picture once you must constantly refresh?  Even if there is no movement of the screen?  Also what is meant by too early?  Display command position in the program, or in relation to the event loop?   Sorry for being slow.  I have minimal event driven program experience.  Mine have been top down with stop and wait for response type thing.

Comment: @AceBlackwell that particular question is quite frequent on stackoverflow, that could be counted as 'complaining'. Funny part is that long time ago it seemed to "work" (unless you hide window or overshadow it by another window), but nowadays with compositing window managers it mostly don't. What happens is you send window contents to be displayed before your window is visible; you don't have to do anything specific here, just (re)draw when SDL asks you to. There is no need to constant redraw, check last part of my answer, you can wait for event, and redraw if that event is WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED

Comment: Understood.  Thanks.  I'm already trying out other tutorials.  I'm thinking understanding different approaches along with your info, I'll get a grasp on it.   Thanks again.